# Google Apps Script getResponseCode() function not working

Tags: api, google-apps-script

I am writing code for API integration using Apps script and I have written similar scripts for more then 300 APIs integrations.
I am facing some surprising issues while retrieving data using API.

```
  var options = {
      "method" : "GET",
      "headers" : {
        "muteHttpExceptions" : false,
        "Content-Type" : "application/json", 
        "followRedirects": false,
        "Authorization": apikey
      }
     }


 var ResCadence = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API End point", options);
 Logger.log("Get Response Code = " + ResCadence.getResponseCode());
```

Following is the log.

> Exception: Request failed for API_End_Point returned code 404.
> Truncated server response: {"error":"Not found"} (use
> muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

The API getResponseCode() not working and do not return any code but exception show that it returned 404 code.
My custom log to return response code didn't return any log.
Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Hi there! In order to replicate this behaviour, could you please clarify what is the used API endpoint? To discard an endpoint issue, could you please test another endpoint?

Comment: I am facing this issue since two APIs. One was SageOne and second is SalesLoft. I feel this isn't API issue as i test in postman and return codes are exist. This is Apps script issue.

Comment: I noticed it only happens with 404 and 401 codes.

Comment: I've been testing this approach and it works on my side. You said «*This is Apps script issue*», could you please show why are you sure of that? Please edit your question and add any relevant info. To discard an API issue, please test the code against a well-known API ([Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) per example) and write back sharing your findings.

Comment: Show your `options` object @KashifIqbal

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contribution. I find the answer from google for this issue.
I put the `"muteHttpExceptions" : false,` in heads block and it should be out side the header block. i.e

```
  var options = {
      "method" : "GET",
      "muteHttpExceptions" : false,
      "headers" : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json", 
        "followRedirects": false,
        "Authorization": apikey
      }
     }
```